# Undefining leftbar environment to eliminate multiple definitions in memoir class and thmbox package

Tags: environments, memoir, thmbox

Context : I am using the memoir class, and I was trying to use the `thmbox` package. But the environment `leftbar` is defined both in `memoir` and `thmbox`.

So I was trying to undefine an environment but I was just able to find how to undefine a command. By using

```
\let\command\undefined
```

So I was able to undefined an environment by doing

```
\let\env\undefined
\let\endenv\undefined
```

But I don't know if it is the proper way to do so. Is there a better way ?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Work by adding these two lines.
\let\leftbar\undefined
\let\endleftbar\undefined

\usepackage{thmbox}

\begin{document}
  Hello.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can be done this way.

An alternative is using `\relax`, because LaTeX also considers this "undefined". Example, `memoir` "undefines" some environments, if package `framed` is loaded:

```
\AtBeginPackage{framed}{%
  \let\framed\relax \let\endframed\relax
  \let\shaded\relax \let\endshaded\relax
  \let\leftbar\relax \let\endleftbar\relax
  \let\snugshade\relax \let\endsnugshade\relax}
```

Also the old meaning can be kept with a different name:

```
\let\memoirleftbar\leftbar
\let\endmemoirleftbar\endleftbar
\let\leftbar\undefined
\let\endleftbar\undefined
```

Alternatives for `\undefined`:

- The LaTeX kernel uses `\@undefined` (but in the preamble, `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is needed):

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \let\leftbar\@undefined
  \let\endleftbar\@undefined
  \makeatother
  ```
- Sometimes I am using something like `\UnDeFiNeD`.